# NatTable - Newest row first

Tags: nattable

Is there a default flag that can be set in NatTable to allow the newest added row to appear at the top of the table?  Or do I just directly add the row to the beginning of a backingList that is maintained by the EventList?  Or do I add it to the sortedList/filterList layers? Or is there another preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special for that in NatTable. You can solve this either by ordering (add the newest item at the beginning) or sorting (find some attribute that can be used to sort the list in the way you want)